# Barplot with columns that are of identical height and fill the entire scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm trying to create a barplot like this where the bars are of different hight (length in the picture though).

[image]

But my code creates this

[image]

I think `geom_col` is the right option here, but I don't know what's wrong with the rest of the code. The columns should not be the same hight.

My code

```
# Add a new column to indicate age group
young$age_group <- "Young"
old$age_group <- "Old"

# Combine the data frames
combined_df <- bind_rows(young, old)

# Plot
ggplot(combined_df, aes(x = age_group, y = implvdm, fill = gndr)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  labs(x = "Age Group", y = "implvdm", fill = "Gender") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Sample data

```
young <- structure(list(gndr = c("woman", "man", "man", "man", "woman", 
"man", "man", "woman", "woman", "man"), yrbrn = c(2003L, 1999L, 
1998L, 1999L, 2002L, 1999L, 2001L, 2004L, 2004L, 1999L), agea = c(18L, 
22L, 23L, 22L, 19L, 22L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 22L), impdema = c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), implvdm = c(10L, 7L, 9L, 
7L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 10L), accalaw = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L), imwbcnt = c(9L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 0L, 10L, 
2L, 3L, 7L, 6L), euftf = c(4L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 
9L), freehms = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), gincdif = c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), prtclffi = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

old <- structure(list(gndr = c("man", "woman", "woman", "man", "woman", 
"man", "woman", "woman", "woman", "woman"), yrbrn = c(1943L, 
1975L, 1974L, 1977L, 1959L, 1993L, 1990L, 1993L, 1958L, 1971L
), agea = c(78L, 46L, 47L, 44L, 63L, 27L, 31L, 29L, 63L, 50L), 
    impdema = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L), implvdm = c(10L, 
    9L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 10L), accalaw = c(0L, 8L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 0L), imwbcnt = c(9L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 7L), euftf = c(8L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
    3L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 5L), freehms = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 1L), gincdif = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L), prtclffi = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you trying to plot the mean of `implvdm`? If so you either need to precompute it (e.g., `combined_df %>% summarize(implvdm = mean(implvdm), .by = c(gndr, age_group))`, or use `geom_bar()` with `stat = "summary"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot won't do any summarizing for you by default with a standard bar plot. Since you have multiple observations per group, you are basically overplotting the bars on top of each other.

If you want to calculate the mean and standard error, you can use `state_summary` instead. For example

```
ggplot(combined_df, aes(x = age_group, y = implvdm, fill = gndr)) +
  stat_summary(position = "dodge", geom="bar") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se,  geom = "errorbar", position=position_dodge(.9), width=.2) + 
  labs(x = "Age Group", y = "implvdm", fill = "Gender") +
  theme_minimal()
```

produces
[image]

You can also use `dplyr` to precompute the values yourself before plotting

```
combined_df %>% 
  summarize(mean=mean(implvdm), se=sd(implvdm)/sqrt(length(implvdm)), .by=c(age_group, gndr)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = age_group, fill = gndr)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = mean), position="dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), position=position_dodge(.9), width=.3) + 
  labs(x = "Age Group", y = "implvdm", fill = "Gender") +
  theme_minimal()
```